# How to format date in JSTL

Tags: datetime, jstl, formatdatetime

I have a loop that goes through all the news items we have on our site. One of the fields is date `${newsitem.value['Date']}`, given in millliseconds. I'd like to display this date in month/day/year format on the webpage. I thought JSTL format tag, `<fmt:formatDate>`, would help, but I haven't succeeded. Do you know how to do it?

```
<cms:contentaccess var="newsitem" />
<h2><c:out value="${newsitem.value['Title']}" /></h2>
// display date here        
<c:out value="${newsitem.value['Text']}"  escapeXml="false" />
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes the JSTL `formatDate` tag should do the job in combination with changing the Timestamp value into a date object (which is required to work around the exception mentioned in your comment).

Ensure that you have properly defined the `fmt` prefix in the JSP declarations

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

Render the output, convert the time stamp to a date value first. I'm using `yyyy-MM-dd` as the [format pattern](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the `dateFormat` tag supports [other formatting options](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) as well.

```
<cms:contentaccess var="newsitem" />
<jsp:useBean id="newsDate" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:setProperty name="newsDate" property="time" value="${newsitem.value['Date']}" />
<h2><c:out value="${newsitem.value['Title']}" /></h2>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${newsDate}" />
<c:out value="${newsitem.value['Text']}" escapeXml="false" />
```

Comment: I've tried this earlier but it throws this error:
"Cannot convert 1270738800000 of type class org.opencms.jsp.util.CmsJspContentAccessValueWrapper to class java.util.Date"

Comment: I've tried without <cms:contentaccess var="newsitem" /> and it works.