# How to use format date as "yyyy-MM-dd" with JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl

I want to take date from DB and display on jsp:

> 2014-04-02

instead of:

> 2014-04-02 00:00:00.0

On jsp I tried to use **c:fmt** tag for formatting date:

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <span><fmt:message key="task.start"/></span>
      <input class="form-control" id="firstDate" placeholder="<fmt:message key="task.start"/>" 
           name="start_date-${task.taskId}"
         <fmt:formatDate value="${task.startDate}" var="startFormat" type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        value="${startFormat}"/>
   </div>
```

Looking on the page:

[image: view]

How to format it to **yyyy-MM-dd** format?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620676/how-to-format-date-in-jstl

Comment: relevant doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html and also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First you need to add the line below to head of your jsp file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Now you can use `<fmt:formatDate>` and `<fmt:parseDate>` for formatting date.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="yy-MMM-dd"/>
```

PS: In your code, I saw you had some mistakes with the jsp tag. I think it should be

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <span><fmt:message key="task.start"/></span>
      <input class="form-control" id="firstDate" placeholder="<fmt:message key='task.start'/>" 
           name="start_date-${task.taskId}" value="<fmt:formatDate value='${task.startDate}' var='startFormat' type='date' pattern='yyyy-MM-dd'/>"
   </div>
```

Answer (score 13):

The `value` for `fmt:formatDate` is suppose to be a Date object (`java.util.Date`). If the `task.startDate` is a date as a String, then you need to convert it beforehand.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${task.startDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="myDate"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${myDate}" var="startFormat" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

Comment: it is `java.util.Date`