# Value have changed when pass value between 2 jsp pages

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 jsp page, i sent value from frist page to second page, but when i show value in input tag, the value have changed. What wrong with my coded?
The first page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
            showOn: "focus"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

JSP:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></p>
```

And Servlet:

```
HttpSession s= request.getSession();
String olddate= (String)request.getParameter("datepicker");
s.setAttribute("DATE", olddate);    
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("nextpage.jsp");
```

The second Page JSP:

```
<%
HttpSession s= request.getSession();
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String date = s.getAttribute("DATE").toString();
Date dateto = sdf.parse(date);
String newDateString = sdf.format(dateto);
    %>
<p>Date From: <input type="text" id="datefrompicker" readonly="readonly">/p>
```

And Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var date =<%=newDateString%>;
        alert(dateto);
        $( "#datefrompicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", date );       
    });
```

The first page value is 2015/11/01,the value in alert is 91.5909090909091, and input datefrompicker don't have any thing.

What am i do wrong?

Comment: after this line `var date =<%=date %>;` just print date value like `alert('<%=date%>' and let me know if any string is getting printed in alert.

Comment: The value print in alert is correct? But the value show in input tag is wrong. What is problem :( ?

Comment: Please tell me the value here.

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with converting date types in JSP to JS? Maybe you should try using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824190/how-to-use-format-date-at-jsp-with-jstl-tag

Comment: So the method setDate in datepicker is wrong.

Comment: @rajuGT Value in first page is 2015/11/01 and the value in the second page is 2016/05/04.

Comment: @thefriend year format in the declaration and in the alert are mismatching. Update my answer check it. Use SimpleDateFormat if needed.

Comment: @thefriend `String olddate= (String)request.getParameter("datepicker");` print using sysout what is the value in `olddate`

Comment: Value printed is 2015/11/04

Answer (score 0):

In first code section `dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",` the year format in the alert date string **yyyy**, so use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format accordingly.

The `Date.toString` method returns date string which cannot be parsed by [DatePicker.setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method.

**Example:**

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

Please use the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date string and everything should work fine.

Comment: I have change code but why value is unintelligible.

Comment: I think there is no need of DateFormat, change `$( "#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",` to `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",` i.e. yy to yyyy

Comment: DateFormat yyyy/mm/dd will display year 2 times.